# Wrapper function with if conditions

Tags: r

Could someone please tell me how to combine wrapper function with if..else conditions? For example this wrapper:

```
wrapper<-function(x){
  varcoef<-function(x){
    sd(x)/mean(x)
  }
  apply(x,MARGIN = 2, FUN=varcoef)
}

wrapper(mtcars)
```

With:

```
if(is.matrix(x)==TRUE){
  apply(x,2,function(x) sd(x)/mean(x))
} else if (is.data.frame(x)==TRUE){
  apply(x,2,function(x) sd(x)/mean(x))
} else print(NULL)
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are applying the same code irrespective if the data is matrix or dataframe. Why do you need `if`/`else` here then?

Comment: @RonakShah Hi, it was just an example - I need to solve an IF condition for case when the object is vector and I want the result to be just one number.. but i didnt solve it so far, so i used this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally to handle different classes (matrix, data.frame) one creates a generic and dispatches to a method for each class as opposed to using `if`.  This provides a modular approach in which new classes can be added without modifying the existing code -- just add a new method.

```
wrapper <- function(x, ...) {
  varcoef <- function(x) sd(x) / mean(x)
  UseMethod("wrapper")
}

wrapper.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
  is.num <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  apply(x[is.num], 2, varcoef)
}

wrapper.matrix <- function(x, ...) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
  apply(x, 2, varcoef)
}

# tests

wrapper(CO2)

m <- as.matrix(BOD)
wrapper(m)
```

If you want to use `if` anyways then:

```
wrapper <- function(x, ...) {
  varcoef <- function(x) sd(x) / mean(x)
  if (inherits(x, "data.frame")) {
    is.num <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
    apply(x[is.num], 2, varcoef)
  } else {
    stopifnot(is.numeric(x))
    apply(x, 2, varcoef)
  }
}
   
# tests

wrapper(CO2)

m <- as.matrix(BOD)
wrapper(m)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, I see what you're doing there but I need one wrapper function with if conditions :/ its the requirement. Aaand please, how can i combine it also with a condition when the object is a vector? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If by vector you mean something that has no dimensions or 1 dimension then test it for `length(dim(x)) < 2` .  For example these have 0, 1 and 2 dimensions respectively: 1:3, array(1:3), mtcars .